# How does one mount UNC root? (SMB / CIFS)

Tags: mount, 18.04, samba, cifs

I'm in a situation where I need to mount the UNC root, i.e. "\" or "smb://". I can open up nautilus and go to "smb://" but I need to actually do things with that, such as: readdir, mkdir, unlink, rmdir, open, read, write, etc. from the standard POSIX filesystem APIs. Is there existing software that lets me do that?

I've tried `mount -t cifs "//"` but it gives me

> mount error: UNC name too short

I've also tried `mount -t cifs "smb://"` but that gives me a

> Mounting cifs URL not implemented yet. Attempt to mount smb://

I've tried all those smb commands of old, but they're no longer present - I believe which have moved to cifs instead. I've also tried these fancy new gvfs / gio things, which I suppose is a gobject based userland mounting system, but  `gio mount smb://` gives me...

> gio: smb:///: Location is already mounted

... Mounted where? I can go to it in nautilus, but again I can't do anything with that. I thought it might be mounted at /run/user/1000/gvfs but that program-fuse-folder-thing doesn't seem to do much on it's own unless I specifically mount things using the command.

I don't even really require to be able to list smb:// or even smb://server/, but I need ALL smb://server/shares/ to be available, which the same functionality as if I had mounted them using smb or gvfs (e.g. listing, making folders, deleting things, opening files, and also authentication).

To further clarify, any and all applications need to be able to basic perform filesystem API functions on any and all unc paths, at least to the extent provided by gvfs or cifs. For example, I should be able to:

```
cd /some/path/server1/share1/folder1
cat file1
mkdir newfolder2
cd ../existingfolder3
touch file2
cd /some/path/server2/share2
rmdir existingfolder4
```

... etc. Bonus points if I could `ls /some/path/server1`

There are plenty of fuse libraries out there, so I was considering writing a little script that automatically mounted the shares when requested, and then just passing through the commands to the mount points, but I certainly don't want to reinvent the wheel, and I'd also love for something much for portable than anything I would have the time to develop. But if this is the easiest way then I can start writing some code and either post it here or start a new question when I need help with it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it...

It's called [smbnetfs](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Smbnetfs).

It does everything I asked for in the question, although for listing and some other operations it's really slow.

Answer (score 3):

*Just as a side note: Every time someone on earth creates a smb / samba share of the root directory of a machine a Network Administrator in heaven loses his wings.*

> I've tried mount -t cifs "//"

Your syntax is wrong, it's incomplete, and you can't designate a share on the server as "/".

[1] Go to the server and create a share of "/" if that is what you truly want to do but name the share ... I don't know ... how about "root"

[2] Create a mount point on the client to mount the share - let's say /home/agnes/servername

```
mkdir /home/agnes/servername
```

[3] Then mount with a command that looks something like this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //servername/root /home/agnes/servername -o some-list-of-options
```

Will it do everything you want it to do in your original post? I have no idea.

You can also go old school I guess and use smbclient:

```
smbclient //servername/root
```

You will end up with the prompt:

> smb: >

If you enter help you will see the list of commands at your disposal:

> ?              allinfo        altname        archive        backup
> blocksize      cancel         case_sensitive cd             chmod
> chown          close          del            deltree        dir
> du             echo           exit           get            getfacl
> geteas         hardlink       help           history        iosize
> lcd            link           lock           lowercase      ls
> l              mask           md             mget           mkdir
> more           mput           newer          notify         open
> posix          posix_encrypt  posix_open     posix_mkdir
> posix_rmdir     posix_unlink   posix_whoami   print          prompt
> put             pwd            q              queue          quit
> readlink        rd             recurse        reget          rename
> reput           rm             rmdir          showacls       setea
> setmode         scopy          stat           symlink        tar
> tarmode         timeout        translate      unlock         volume
> vuid            wdel           logon          listconnect
> showconnect    tcon            tdis           tid            logoff
> ..

Comment: Fantastic reply, thank you. I like the remark at the beginning too, but I am working with a windows-related thing so that's to be expected of course xD

But this still doesn't solve my problem unfortunately - I have something that expects the exact same api for browsing the UNC root as it does the files inside of a samba share. Modifying the thing is not an option for both the reasons that it's not the simplest and more direct thing to do, but also another reason which I will not list. I would prefer to use the same API everything else in Linux is using, because that seems most correct.

Comment: And also,
`Your syntax is wrong, it's incomplete, and you can't designate a share on the server as "/"`
It is wrong and incomplete which is why I'm asking for help, but I'm not trying to designate a share on a server as "/", I'm asking for something that will automatically translate that for me.

Answer (score 0):

As far I can understand - the `smbtree` command will do what you want.

From its [`man smbtree`-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/smbtree.1.html):

> **NAME**
> `smbtree` - A text based smb network browser
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> This tool is part of the samba(7) suite.
>
> `smbtree` is a smb browser program in text mode. It is similar to the "Network Neighborhood" found on Windows computers. It prints a tree with all the known domains, the servers in those domains and the shares on the servers.

Comment: Hey, this is a spectacular tool, thank you! Especially for answering so quickly. But I should probably clarify in my question that I need to be able to: readdir, mkdir, unlink, rmdir, open, read, etc. from the standard POSIX filesystem API with the smb monts.

Comment: I recommend to read [Samba documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/) and determine how they do all these things. From my experience we have two stages - share discovery and share mount. Discovery is done by `smbtree` and `smbclient -L host`. Then mounted share may be manipulated by `cifs-utils`, `smbmount`, GVFS and so on. Also see [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Samba#Client) for brief information about Samba.

Comment: So then I would need the share share discovery and share mount stages to happen without any interaction at all. I'll take a look through the documentation links and report back, thanks!